# Windows Azure reliability (my server just lost its drives & sites, then 20 minutes later they reappeared)

Tags: azure

I am on a Windows Azure trial to evaluate migrating a number of commercial ASP.NET sites to Azure from dedicated hosting. All was going OK ... until just now!

Some background - the sites are set up under Web Roles (i.e. as opposed to Web Sites) using SQL Azure and SQL Reporting. The site content was under the X: drive (there was also a B: drive that seemed to be mapped to the same location). There are several days left of the trial.

Without any apparent warning my test sites suddenly stopped working. Examining the server (through RDP) I saw that the B: and X: drives had disappeared (just C: D & E: I think were left), and in IIS the application pools and Sites had disappeared. In the Portal however, nothing seemed to have changed - the same services & config seemed to be there.

Then about 20 minutes later the missing drives, app pools and sites reappeared and my test sites started working again! However, the B: drive was gone and now there was an F: drive (showing the same as X:); also the MS ReportViewer 2008 control that I had installed earlier in the day was gone. It is almost as if the server had been replaced with another (but the IIS config was restored from the original).

As you can imagine, this makes me worried! If this is something that could happen in production there is no way I would consider hosting commercial sites for clients on Azure (unless there is some redundancy system available to keep a site up when such a failure occurs).

Can anyone explain what may have happened, if this is possible/predictable under a live subscription, and if so how to work around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One other thing to keep in mind is that an Azure Web Role is not persistent.  I'm not sure how you installed the MS Report Viewer 2008 control but anything you add or install outside of a deployment package when you push your solution to Azure is not guaranteed to be available at some future point.

I admit that I don't fully understand the full picture when it comes to the overall architecture of Azure but I do know that Web Roles can and do re-create themselves from time to time.  When the role recycles, it returns to the state as it was when it was installed.  This is why Microsoft suggests using at least 2 instances of your role because while one or the other may recycle they will never recycle both at the same time, part of what guarantees the 99.9% uptime.

You might also want to consider an Azure VM.  They are persistent but require you to maintain the server in terms of updates and software much in the way I suspect you are already doing with your dedicated hosting.

I've been hosting my solution in a large (4 core) web role, also using SQL Azure, for about two years and have had great success with it.  I have roughly 3,000 users and rarely see the utilization of my web role go over 2% (meaning I've got a lot of room to grow).  Overall it is a great hosting solution in my opinion.

Comment: The recycling makes (some) sense. However control of the server via Remote Desktop is allowed so its rather alarming to be able to install something then see it disappear!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Azure SLA](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/) Microsoft guarantees up time of 99.9% or higher on all its products per billing month.  (20 min on the month would be .0004% loss, not being critical, just suggesting that they are still within their SLA)

[Current status](http://azurestatus.cloudapp.net/) shows that sql databases were having issues in the US north last night, but all services [appear to be up currently](https://www.windowsazurestatus.com/windowsazure/support/status/servicedashboardcontent.aspx)

Personally, I have seen the dashboard go down, and report very weird problems, but the services that I programmed to worked just fine all the way through it.  When I experienced this problem it was reported on the [Azure Status](http://azurestatus.cloudapp.net/), the [platform status](https://www.windowsazurestatus.com/windowsazure/support/status/servicedashboardcontent.aspx) and the [twitter feed](https://twitter.com/azurestatus)

While I have seen bumps, they are few and far between, and I find reliability to be perceptibly higher than other providers that I have worked with.

As for workarounds I would suggest a standard mode for your websites and increasing instances of the site.  You might try looking into the new add ins that are available with the latest Azure release.  [Active Cloud Monitoring](https://www.metricshub.com/azureonboarding/start) by Metrichub might be what you require.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're expecting the web role to act as a Virtual Machine instance.

Web Roles aren't persistent (the machine can be destroyed and recreated at any time), so you should do any additional required set up as a 'startup task' in your Azure project (never install software manually).

Because of this you need at least 2 instances so that rolling upgrades (i.e. Windows security patches, hotfixes and so on) can be performed automatically without having your entire deployment taken offline.

If this doesn't suit your use case then you should look at Azure Virtual Machines, but you'll need to manage updates and so on yourself. It's usually better to use Web Roles properly as you can then do scaling and so on a lot more easily.